# New dot net core 3.0 preview console project - stack overflow error: VS 2019 16.2.0

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

When I create a dot net core 3.0 (SDK 3.0.100-preview7-012821) console project (or any core project) it can't be run. It just instantly throws a stack overflow error.

Is the preview bugged or incompatible with the latest Visual Studio 2019 16.2.0 version?

Comment: It is supposed to be used with 16.3 preview 1 and above. Does updating VS to the latest preview fix it?

Comment: I tried it on another machine with the same setup and it works. So it somehow must be related to the computer. Maybe the installation is corrupted...